# Adobe Flash CS4 and Adobe Flash CS6: How to export for one another?

Tags: adobe-flash, downgrade, adobe-cs4, flash-cs6

A friend of mine asked me for help on a Flash project. I agreed.

I had no prior experience in working with Flash, but I was surprised how comfortable it is to program in AS3, so I was actually quite happy I was helping him.

There is one problem though: I got Adobe Flash CS6, and he still uses Adobe Flash CS4. Now, I was able to import a CS4 `.fla` into CS6 without any problems, but the other way round, seems to be impossible.

I *can* export to CS5 and CS5.5, but not below that.

Now, since I was just helping, etc. and it is basically his work, I should give all I've done back, but how am I supposed to do that? All I came up with, is suggesting him to upgrade to at least CS5 - or better CS6, so he could open and edit my file.

If there is another option or service of "downgrading" CS6 `.fla`'s to a former version, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't save it directly. Every flash version only allows saving to 1 version below itself.
You could save it to CS5, then download a trial version of Flash CS5, open the file and save it back to CS4.

Comment: Serious? This kinda sucks... X_X

Comment: That's the problem with commercial software.  They dump tons of money into building something no one asked for in particular, they throw it onto the market and expect everyone to use it, but they keep the source code closed, so you must use the software on their terms, at their price, with the features locked to what they feel like implementing, and if it's broken or missing something TOO BAD - HEY PAY US AGAIN FOR UPGRADE!  In their dreams.  Terrible model. That's why I use GIMP, Flex SDK, and FlashDevelop... all free.